# How to display Layout like below in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Here i want to create a layout that contains following by using fragment how can i do this?
Should i use  for top portion or can i use fragment? which one is the best approach. And instead of swipe tab i want to display `.(dot)` in the bottom. e.g. Android home screen bottom 3-5 dots.

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|  +------------+                               |
|  |            |           Line 1              |
|  |  Image     |           Line 2              |
|  |            |           Line 3              |
|  |            |        (Static)               |
|  +------------+                               |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|      Some Content goes here                   |
|            (Swipe tab)                        |
|              Swipe to next -->>>              |
|       Here dot(.) represent the pages         |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|____________________._._.______________________|
|                                               |
|     3 images goes here                        |
|          (Static Horizontal scroll able)      |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm...i tried it...and here is the out put...

[image]

And here is the source...

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/news_item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="Test image"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your headline..."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your text here..."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your text here..."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFCCCCCC" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Inner contents..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</FrameLayout>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scrollable contents here..."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

NOTE: You need to put your tabs or any thing else in Inner contents section. And whatever contents in lower scrollable panel by you self. I just tried to make a structure for you...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks a lot. i want exactly like this. Instead of frame layout i want to use view pager So can i do this by fragment. and instead of swipe tab i want to put .(dot) that will display no. of or which pages and which page user is.

Comment: just one last thing @umair.ali can i put .(dot) in bottom in place of swipe tab??

Comment: Hmmm...thats a hole different story...it would be better to look for some builtin or custom control to give you such feature of having dot like thing four you tabs. You can implement it your self but it may cost much time and extra effort...so look for some other control...:)

Comment: How should i search for that?? @Umair.ali

Comment: Hmmm...you need to go for ViewPagger...have look at this link...https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 0):

You must put three layouts . In first linear horizontal layout place imageview and text views.
In the second one place a horizontal scrollable view with buttons or something suits to you contents with match parent widht to each . place page indicator tyo each button. 
Third one is normal scrollable view or use gallery view to place you content.